# Add magnifier icon to kendo auto complete in Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, autocomplete

i'm using kendo autocomplete in my angular project, How can i use magnifier image inside the autocomplete box? Suggest me some live example or code.Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you want to place it? Should it have some functionality?

Comment: i want to place it inside the autocomplete box

Comment: @swagath I think my comment is very late, but have you found the way to implement the icon?